# Biblatex: remove dots from abbreviated journal title

Tags: biblatex

I am using the "authoryear" style in biblatex. In the bibliography, the journal name is abbreviated using dots (e.g. "Am. J. Epidemiol."). Is there a way to get rid of the dots to obtain "Am J Epidemiol"? Thank you!

EDIT: here is a MWE. What I want to get is Am J Epidemiol, without the dots. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, terseinits=TRUE, isbn=false, url=false, doi=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{kim2013,
title = {Prediction of Severe, Persistent Activity-of-Daily-Living Disability in Older Adults},
volume = {178},
issn = {0002-9262, 1476-6256},
url = {http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/178/7/1085},
doi = {10.1093/aje/kwt097},
language = {en},
number = {7},
urldate = {2016-01-28},
journal = {Am. J. Epidemiol.},
author = {Kim, Dae Hyun and Newman, Anne B. and Lipsitz, Lewis A.},
month = oct,
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
This is just a filler \parencite{kim2013}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: A full minimal working example would be most comfortable for users, but you should show at least the bib-entry.

Comment: I guess you have too many files to do clear the dots by hand in all journal fields?

Comment: My actual bib files contains about 100 citations. If it were a one-time issue I would not bother, but it will replicate everytime I will need to use a bib file generated from a collection in Zotero (a reference management software).

Answer (score 7):

biber can be used to on the fly modification of the data in the bibtex entries.

Thus a possible solution is to use a map that uses regular expression to remove `.`, namely:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{ 
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
           \step[fieldsource=journal, match=\regexp{\.}, replace={ }]
          }
    }      
}
```

With the provided MWE we obtain:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer :-)

Comment: Thank you! Where should I put the code? In the tex file or will it work also from within the bbx file, so that I don't have to repeat the code in every tex file?

Comment: In every tex file.