# Biblatex: remove dots from abbreviated journal title and insert spaces instead

Tags: biblatex

Similar to [Biblatex: remove dots from abbreviated journal title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291078/biblatex-remove-dots-from-abbreviated-journal-title)

How can I remove the dots in the abbreviated journal title and insert a space (" ") instead?

What do I have to put in the replace brackets of the command?

```
\DeclareSourcemap{ 
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
           \step[fieldsource=journal, match=\regexp{\.}, replace={ }]
          }
    }      
}
```

My coding example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear,firstinits=true,terseinits=true,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{} %http://projekte.dante.de/DanteFAQ/BiblatexInBeiArticleUnterdr%fccken

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}} %http://projekte.dante.de/DanteFAQ/BiblatexFeldUnterdr%fccken
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{abstract}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}



%http://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/d5x9LIG5/biblatex-anpassung-eines-bibliography-styles
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot} %journal titel nicht kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\isdot} %titel bei misc nicht kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1} %Seite weglassen.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % keine anführungszeichen um Titel bei allen Artikeln

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} % Doppelpunkt nach letztem Autor

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} %Komma zwischen Nachnamen und Vornamen weg 

% Schlüssel als Zahlen in eckigen Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}


% Doppelpunkt nach journal 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249010/adding-comma-after-journal-name-in-biblatex
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}


% mit terseinits=true in den Optionen für biblatex -> enfernt die Punkte nach den Initialen
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65438/removing-full-stop-after-first-name-initial-in-biblatex-for-all-authors
\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
     {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%      \ifblank{#2}{}{\addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}% DELETED
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}% NEW
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%      \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}% DELETED
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Zuerst das Datum aus dem Autor entfernen:
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
%  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}%
}
% Dann das Jahr am Ende wieder einfügen und den Punkt am Ende weglassen:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}{\usebibmacro{finentry}}{\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}{}{}

%\DeclareSourcemap{ 
%    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
%      \map{
%           \step[fieldsource=journal, match=\regexp{\.}, replace={~}]
%          }
%    }      
%}

%\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{RefWorks:1,
    author={H. Müller and R. Meier and X. Schultze},
    year={2013},
    title={Möglichkeiten zur Proliferation von Dissertationen},
    journal={J.Comp.Neurol.},
    volume={55},
    pages={11-55},
}

@article{RefWorks:2,
    author={K. Schröder},
    year={2015},
    title={Nobelpreiswürdig},
    journal={Paper of Excellence},
    volume={1},
    number={9},
    pages={89-96},
    note={viel zusaeztliche Informationen},
    keywords={Deutschland; Europa; Literatur; Wissenschaft},
    isbn={1524-4539; 0009-7322},
    language={eng},
    pmid={12485966}
}
\end{filecontents}

\nocite{*} %nur bibliographie ausgeben
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}




 \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

leads to

[image: bibliography example]

Comment: Use `\space`. See Biblatex's manual for details. At least, that's what I'd think. But you seem to already know about `\space` yet don't mention trying it. So probably I'm wrong.

Comment: \space did work now. I tried it before but no idea what was different

Answer (score 1):

the simple command of \space solved it.

```
%\DeclareSourcemap{ 
%    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
%      \map{
%           \step[fieldsource=journal, match=\regexp{\.}, replace={\space}]
%          }
%    }      
%}
```